# Ansible: How force kill process and exit from ansible-playbook if not successful?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have two bellow tasks as part from my playbook

```yaml
  - name: "Verify httpd.service no running on node {{ ansible_hostname }}"
    shell: "ps -ef | grep httpd"
    register: _ps_httpd
    become: true

  - name: stop httpd is exit code eq to 0
    shell: "kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep httpd| awk '{print $2}')"
    when: _ps_httpd.rc == 0
    become: true
    ignore_errors: true
```

This two tasks that should force kill process. Currently I'm getting the error

```yaml
"msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": -9
```

What do I miss here? Any idea how to get resolve this?

In addition, I would like to add the option exit from `ansible-playbook` run if not successful.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the goal in Ansible it is recommended in general to use service modules, [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html), [`sysvinit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sysvinit_module.html) or [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html). In example like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Gathering Service Facts
    service_facts:

  - name: Make sure service is stopped
    systemd:
      name: httpd
      state: stopped
      enabled: no
    when: ("httpd.service" in services)
```

If you like to use the `shell`_module, for me more work was necessary.

In example for `nginx` get the right PID first, since there are a primary and four worker processes.

```yaml
- name: Get nginx PID
  shell:
    cmd: "ps -C nginx -o pid --no-headers | head 1"
    warn: false
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  register: nginx_pid
```

It would also be possible to do something like

```yaml
- name: Get nginx PIDs
  shell:
    cmd: "pidof nginx"
    warn: false
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  register: nginx_pids

- name: Show PIDs
  debug: 
    var: nginx_pids

- name: Kill nginx
  shell:
    cmd: "kill -9 {{ nginx_pids }}"
  ...
```

Regarding

> *I would like to add the option exit from ansible-playbook run if not successful.*

to [end the playbook run](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameters) you could use

```yaml
- meta: end_play
  when: condition_is_met
```

use [`fail`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html)_module to

```yaml
- name: Task has failed because of
  fail:
    msg: "{{ fail_message }}"
  when: condition_is_met
```

or the [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html)_module.

Regarding the exit code (EC) or return code (RC) you may have a look into [How do I get the list of exit codes (and/or return codes) and meaning for a command/utility?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110348/).

**Similar Q&A**

with the same error message

- [Why does Ansible think this shell command has a non-zero return code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75108720/6771046)

Comment: Sometimes killing is necessary, but kill -9 is rather hard, because the process cannot react on -SIGKILL.